# Difference between Berlin CityTourCard, Berlin WelcomeCard or 7-Tage-Karte for 8 days' stay?

Tags: budget, tickets, germany, transportation, berlin

I am going to travel in Berlin for 8 days with a friend. I saw these three options which cover public transportation cost and more:

- Berlin CityTourCard
  Covers Berlin AB Zone with a list of discounts
  3 versions available: 48hr, 72hr and 5 days
- Berlin WelcomeCard
  One version covers Berlin AB and another one covers ABC and Potsdam, also with a list of discounts
  3 versions available: 48hr, 72hr and 5 days
- 7-Tage-Karte
  Covers Berlin AB Zone, 7 days obviously

Since we are staying for 8 days, which should we choose?
We will be leaving at about 4pm on the last day, so we may only go for some walks in the morning and leave for the airport at noon. Thus, just assume us be traveling for 7 days.

Then, which to choose a combination of a 48hr and 5 days cards? Or just go for a 7-Tage-Karte (28,80€)? Or a combination of a 48hr/72hr card and few Tageskarte (6,70€)?

If a 48hr+5days combination is better, which is more worth the value, CityTourCard (16,90€+29,90€=46.80€ each) or WelcomeCard (18,50€+31,50€=50€)?

Comment: What are you planning to do in and around Berlin? That'll make a big difference to which makes sense!

Comment: We are planning to visit few tourist spots and go around the city to discover something interesting. We don't have many plans so to say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of that combinations are a good budget options, but all depends on what you are planning to do.

Notice, that **Berlin CityTourCard** gives you only **discounts**, not free entry. Another option you should consider is the **[Museumpass Berlin](http://www.visitberlin.de/de/artikel/museumspass-berlin)**, which gives you **free** entry to many musea (thought the list is shorter as the discounts in the CityTourCard).

If you want to see only **Schloss Sanssouci** in Potsdam, you can use **[Einzelfahrausweise für Kurzstrecken](http://www.s-bahn-berlin.de/aboundtickets/kurzstrecke.htm)** (2x 1,50Euro). Palace and park is about a half hour footwalk from S-Bahn station. If you want to see the whole Potsdam, spending them 2 days for example, city card including Potsdam is a good option.

I've spent a week in Berlin using 7-day AB ticket, 3-day Museumpass and 2x Kurzstrecken. It was an optimal plan for me. For you - it depends on what exactly you want to see.

Answer (score 4):

The two tourist cards are only convenient if you plan to visit a lot of the listed attractions, which is an unlikely scenario. Keep in mind that they are only discounts, and they only include minor museums. Otherwise, do as the locals do and go for a 7-day-card.

You won't need a card including zone C for most of your sightseeing. The only destinations outside zone AB are the Schönefeld airport (but if you come from Asia you'll most likely land in the other airport, Tegel) and Potsdam. Both can be covered using a single ticket (as Lukasz suggested, 1.50E, but you'll have to get down the train to stamp it at the last station of zone B) or an extension ticket (Anschlussfahrausweis, 1.60E: allows you to make one trip to the C area with a ticket valid for zones AB).

Note that neither the ABC card nor these solutions will allow you to take local buses in Potsdam. For those you need an extra ticket --- so you can spend 1 hr more in the park rather than walking to and from it.